# An internal error occurred during: "svn update". 3

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

I've merged one branch to another branch and received this error `an internal error occurred during: "svn merge". 3`
After this operation, I am not able to perform any of the svn actions like update, cleanup etc. All these actions leading to the same error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in SVNKit library which is used in Subclipse / Subversive plug-in for Eclipse IDE, see the filed issue [SVNKIT-432](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-432). The issue description in the bugtracker is unclear but it says that automatic reintegration merges (new in SVN 1.8) are not supported by SVNKit library so I guess that you must avoid them for now.